# generating AWGN in matlab

Tags: matlab, noise

I'd like to have your overview if what I'm doing is OK.

I need to plot the BER vs Eb/No. So the noise power which I should generate should be related to Eb/No.

1. bits are encoded into 1/2 rate encoder.
2. the output of the encoder is converted to +1 and -1 symbols
3. symbols are oversampled by OS ratio.
4. the oversampled symbols are passed through Gaussian filter and this is the data which i send to the channel.

now i need to generate AWGN:

```
EbNo_dB_bit_list = -2:0.25:2; 
EsNo_dB_no_code = EbNo_dB_bit_list - 10*log10(OS); 
dec_EsNo_dB_no_code=10.^(-EsNo_dB_no_code/10); 
sigma2 = 1/(2*Rate)*dec_EsNo_dB_no_code; % to include the code rate 

ni = randn(1,length(modulated)); 
nq =randn(1,length(modulated)); 
noise=(ni+1j*nq)*sqrt(sigma2(k));
```

Comment: I don't see any problem on the generated complex gaussian `noise`.

Comment: So all the steps and conversions are OK?

Comment: All you've done are mathematically right, but I can't help you for their technical correctness.
noise generated is what you want

Comment: Looks mostly fine, not sure about the oversampling, though. Have you compared your results with the theoretical results that Matlab's "bertool" gives you for QPSK? That is usually a good way to verify correctness.